# What are these Ford Fiesta buttons?

Tags: ford, fiesta, dashboard

I'm renting a Fiesta, not sure which year. It has these buttons on the dash, what do they do?

[image: Ford Fiesta dashboard buttons with a line and a curved line]

[image: Ford Fiesta dashboard button with a dial and a lamp]

I already figured out that another button changes the color of the mood lighting nonsense.

Comment: Ummm.. push the buttons and see what happens? The second one appears to change the instrument cluster backlight intensity.

Comment: @DavidLively I pushed them and nothing obvious happened.  Pushing random buttons in a car and seeing what they do is not a great strategy, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 of those function buttons.. They are the audio control buttons 1 to 4. They control various audio mode functions like switching between Radio/CD etc.

Comment: I tried to add pictures to this but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the first one is.
The second one adjusts the instrument panel illumination up or down.

Comment: I tried that and didn't see any change, though.

Comment: The control and symbol are DOT-mandated here in the US. The adjustment might only operate when the headlights or sidelights are on, or be invisible in the daytime, or the control may be broken or disconnected.

Comment: I tried again and it does adjust the instrument panel illumination, it's just not very obvious changes.  What DOT mandate covers things like this?

Comment: Look in the FMVSS - the Federal Motor Vehicle Safety Standards.

Comment: `Means must be provided for illuminating the indicators ... Must be adjustable to provide at least two levels of brightness` https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title49-vol6/pdf/CFR-2011-title49-vol6-sec571-101.pdf  I don't see that symbol, though.

Comment: No idea; I assumed it was in the FMVSS, but don't see it either. It does appear on many cars. Shrug.